# Select function based only on month and year

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a column in the MySQL database that stores data as Date 17-6-2021 for example

the user choose a month and year from input fields as follow

```
<form method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label>choose month</label></td>
          <td><input name="month">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>choose year</label></td>
          <td><input name="year">
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <input type="submit" name="add1" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to compare the date chosen by the user with dates stored in the database to get all values within the month and the year
what function should I use??
my purpose here is to generate a monthly report based on user choices

Comment: Use the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions.

Comment: Step one: Don't store a date as `d-m-Y`.  As you have it, you'll have to use `LIKE` or a collection of string mutating functions -- YUCK.  Save yourself the headache.  Redesign your database table.  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/422047 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817724/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-string-data-type-for-dates-in-mysql-instead-of-using-da , https://stackoverflow.com/q/47764226/2943403

Comment: i already have the database data stored like this because it get the data from date field thats why i want to deal with data stored in this way

Comment: i used the MONTH and YEAR but i didn't get the correct result

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: Store the date using a date data type